# AutoLisp drawing costum polyline

Tags: lisp, autocad, cad, autolisp

**I have this AutoLisp code and I want to ask 2 questins about it:**

**1. how can I make the polyline visible during drawing it(or while selecting the points)?**

**2. how can I change the color of the polyline but not the layer?**

*Many many thanks if i get an answer.*

```
(defun c:nyomvodal (/ osmode clayer celtype)
  ;; save the current osmode, clayer and  celtype
  (setq osmode (getvar "osmode"))
  (setq clayer (getvar "clayer"))
  (setq celtype (getvar "celtype"))

  ;; create a new layer and make it current
  (command "_layer" "_make" "nyomvodal" "_color" 3 "nyomvodal" "")
  ;; set the current osmode and line type
  (setvar "osmode" 0)
  (setvar "celtype" "16-os cso")

  ;; use vla-catch-all-apply to avoid exiting code if user cancels
  (vl-catch-all-apply
    '(lambda (/ pt lst)
       ;; get points form user
       (while (setq pt (getpoint "\nPick point: "))
     (setq lst (cons pt lst))
       )
       (if (< 2 (length lst))
     (progn
       ;; create the polyline
       (command "_pline")
       (foreach p (reverse lst)
         (command p)
       )
       (command "")
     )
       )
     )
  )
  
  ;; restore the previous system variables values
  (setvar "osmode" osmode)
  (setvar "clayer" clayer)
  (setvar "celtype" celtype)
  (princ)
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The easiest would be just run command `PLINE` and wait until user will end.
2. Color You can change by system variable `CECOLOR`.

To restore defaults by system variables You can use error catching (in case when user click <kbd>Esc</kbd> ), when user ends with `[enter]` `[space]` You will restore defaults by call `(*error*)` function

```
(defun c:nyomvodal (/ osmode clayer celtype 
    *error* )   (defun *error* ( msg / ) 
        (if (not (null msg ) )  (progn (princ "\nname:*error*: " ) (princ msg ) (princ "\n")    ) )
        
        (setvar "osmode" osmode)
        (setvar "clayer" clayer)
        (setvar "celtype" celtype)
        (setvar 'CECOLOR cecolor)
    )
  ;; save the current osmode, clayer and  celtype
  (setq osmode (getvar "osmode"))
  (setq clayer (getvar "clayer"))
  (setq celtype (getvar "celtype"))
  (setq cecolor (getvar "CECOLOR"))

  ;; create a new layer and make it current
  (command "_layer" "_make" "nyomvodal" "_color" 3 "nyomvodal" "")
  ;; set the current osmode and line type
  (setvar "osmode" 0)
  (setvar "CECOLOR" "1")
  ;(setvar "celtype" "16-os cso")

  (command "_pline" pause)       
  
  (*error* nil) ; to restore default color, layer ... 
  
  (princ)
)
```